# Metaclass vs inheritance for predefined class creation

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, metaclass

I'm writing some code for a program that will be able to run some software, read the inputs/outputs and do some data processing along the way. For example: (this is not the real case, but just to give an idea)

```python
class MusicFile(object):
   extension = [""]

   def setup(self):
       #set up the data

   def runsoftware(self):
       #play the song

class MP3(MusicFile):
   extension = [".mp3"]

   def setup(self):
       #setupMP3file

   def runsoftware(self):
       #runMP3software
```

I have about 4 general classes, and then file extensions will be defined and treated differently. Each class has a defined number of methods that are required for it to work. For now, only one or two file extensions will be supported, but I want to leave a structure done where adding more extensions is easy (perhaps intuitive) for others to do.

I've been coding for not so long and I was given this task, which I want to do the best possible way.

Is the use of metaclasses appropriate for this case? In order to set up some strict classes that must contain the methods I have previously defined, that way it will be uniform across all of them. Should I stick to just simple inheritance?

I want to be able to maybe have all the subclasses of `MusicFile` registered to be able to instantiate the right one (given a file path, for example).

I have read about metaclasses, and they seem like a good fit for this case, but since I've read also that they don't need to be used if you don't know them very well, I want to ask for your expert opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer only works for Python 3.6+. If you have the option to upgrade to the most recent Python version, [there are numerous reasons why you should](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3/) and the following may be one of them.

Python 3.6 introduced the `__init_subclass__` hook that is exectued after a class is subclassed.

```
class MusicFile:
    _register = {}

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'extension'):
            raise ValueError(cls.__name__ + ' has no extension')

        MusicFile._register.update({e: cls for e in cls.extension})

    @classmethod
    def get_class_by_extension(cls, ext):
        return cls._register.get(ext)
```

#### Example

```
class MP3(MusicFile):
    extension = ['mp3']

class MIDI(MusicFile):
    extension = ['midi']

MusicFile.get_class_by_extension('mp3') # <class '__main__.MP3'>
MusicFile.get_class_by_extension('midi') # <class '__main__.MIDI'>
```

Note that this is very similar to [the factory approach suggested by bipll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51928708/5079316), but in a more straightforward and maintainable way.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to maybe have all the subclasses of MusicFile registered to be able to instantiate the right one (given a file path, for example).

So you probably want to implement [a Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)?

This factory can probably be auto-built with metaclasses. One serious issue I see is using class's own `extension` member to register it, so to me, it is easier done with metaclasses' eternal competition, decorators:

```
class MusicFile(object):
    known_types = {}

    @staticmethod
    def processor(ext):
        return MusicFile.known_types[ext]()

def file_types(*exts):
    def registered_class(cls):
        for ext in exts: MusicFile.known_types[ext] = cls
        return cls
    return registered_class

@file_types('mp3')
class Mp3(MusicFile):
    def greet(self):
        print 'Hi .mp3!'

@file_types('mid', 'midi')
class Midi(MusicFile):
    def greet(self):
        print 'Hi, Music Instruments Digital Interface!'

pcsor = MusicFile.processor('mp3')
pcsor.greet()                      # Hi .mp3!
pcsor = MusicFile.processor('mid')
pcsor.greet()                      # Hi, Music Instruments Digital Interface!
pcsor = MusicFile.processor('midi')
pcsor.greet()                      # Hi, Music Instruments Digital Interface!
pcsor = MusicFile.processor('s3m') # KeyError: 's3m'
pcsor.greet()
```

Comment: Indeed, I’m using a factory so the right object is created, but perhaps the dictionary where it looks could be built by a metaclass every time a new subtype is added? I wonderered if a good use of metaclasses was to create a constraint of how classes will have to look (its methods, for example) in order for it to function