# Return object of the class based on condition

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to return class object based on the condition passed as argument while creating a object.

myclass1.py

```
class myver1():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am in myver1")

    def fun1(self):
        print("I am in method func1 - myver1")

    def fun2(self):
        print("Access this method if version 1 is passed - myver1")

class myver2():
    def __init__(self):
        print("I am in myver2")

    def fun1(self):
        print("I am in method func1 - myvers2")

    def fun2(self):
        print("Access this method if version 2 is passed - myver2")
```

myclass2.py

```
class libtest():
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version
        self.ret_obj

    def ret_obj(self):
        if self.version == 1:
            return myver1()
        if self.version == 2:
            return myver2()
```

```
testobj = libtest(version=1)
testobj.fun1()
```

Expected output:

```
I am in method func1 - myver1
```

Error I see when I run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test44.py", line 12, in <module>
    mytest.myver1()
AttributeError: 'libtest' object has no attribute 'myver1'
```

**Edited:**:
Thank you all, I have called the object as suggested:

```
mytest = libtest(version=2).ret_obj()
mytest.fun1()
```

Is this a right approach? is there any better way?

Comment: Thank you for the clear code code example. What happens when you run it? Please [edit] your question to show an example run.

Comment: @olenscki `version` is an argument to `__init__()`.

Comment: You could do `testobj.ret_obj().fun1()` but I get the feeling you don't want that.  Could you change `libtest` from a class to a function?

Comment: You might want to research metaclasses for an idiomatic, scalable, design. One possible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923555/metaclass-vs-inheritance-for-predefined-class-creation

Comment: The `self.ret_obj` line in the `libtest` class `__init__()` method does nothing. This approach seems awkward. Why are you creating a class with a method that returns an instance of some other class? (This is something you could easily do with just a function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `.ret_obj()` to get the correct `myver` object regarding the version. You can call it at different way, regarding what you want to store in `testobj`

1. Type of `testobj` is `myver1`

   ```
   testobj = libtest(version=1).ret_obj()
   testobj.fun1()
   ```
2. Type of `testobj` is `libtest`

   ```
   testobj = libtest(version=1)
   testobj.ret_obj().fun1()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When I [run your code](https://repl.it/@codeguru/RewardingHarshSmalltalk), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    testobj.fun1()
AttributeError: 'libtest' object has no attribute 'fun1'
```

This tells us that `testobj` is a `libtest` object which doesn't have a function named `fun1`. Looking at the code, we see that `fun1` is in `class myver1` and `class myver2`. You need to call `ret_obj()` to get the correct object:

```
testobj.ret_obj().fun1()
```